# Will the Withdrawal Agreement result in a treaty?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, brexit

If the European Union (Withdrawal Agreement) Bill passes it becomes an Act.

Does it also result in a treaty?

How could a future Government change the intergovernmental element of that Bill

Comment: The [Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_(Withdrawal_Agreement)_Bill_2017%E2%80%9319) is supposed to enshine the [withdrawal agreement/treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit_withdrawal_agreement) in domestic law, not the other way around. Unless you mean something else by "treaty"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is being negotiated between the UK Government and the European Union is a treaty between these two governments.  If it gets ratified by both the UK and European parliaments, it will at that point become a treaty.

The European Union (Withdrawal Agreement) Bill would enact in law what would be required to implement the treaty.